# Google Spreadsheet lookup and return another value

Tags: google-sheets, lookup, gs-vlookup

I'm using google spreadsheet and am trying to search for one value, then return a value in a corresponding cell. So for example, in sheet 2, I want to make a list of all of names in column A (sheet 1) that have a specific value (say 2 for instance) in the corresponding cell in column B. Where do I begin?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be able to use VLOOKUP:

```
VLOOKUP(search_criterion, array, index, sort_order)
```

More info here - [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en)